# Java Observable API - when is it a "pull" scenario?

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I am reading about the Observable pattern (*Head First Design Patterns*) and it is not very clear why it is saying that "You can push or pull data from the Observable when using the pattern".

I understand that you can use the API for subscribing and being notified when something is happening in the Subject/Observable object - eg. each time an event occurs, the Subject/Observable object will call the `notifyObservers` method. This method can be called with or without parameters. Is this difference (with or without parameters) the split between pull and push ?

Put it in other words, if the Subject/Observable object is always calling the registered Observers and never the opposite way, when is it called a pull scenario ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's keep this simple.

- Push: Subject tells (a push) Observers the new data. Observers then do whatever they want with it.
- Pull: Subject tells Observers something changed. This is also a push but 'do it now' is the only data. Observers must then query (a pull) to learn new data. Typically they query the subject.

If you look at it closely enough you can always see pushes mixed with pulls. This is typical but just as you pointed out it's the parameters being pushed or pulled that people focus on when describing the differences in these two patterns.

The Pushy Subject Observer Pattern<sup>TM</sup> also goes by the names Event and Message Passing. The context, intent, and implementation can be very different but the idea is to just tell things to do things. Don't make anything ask and you don't need to expose getters to everything. Avoiding that helps ensure encapsulation.

The draw back is the Pushy Subject must know what data the observer wants. In contrast, A pully observer could grab whatever is accessible to it.

Answer (score 3):

The push and pull scenarios are differentiated on how the registered Observers get to know what actually has changed when they are being called by the Subject/Observable.

In the pull scenario, the call to the Observer contains no information other than that the Subject/Observable has changed. The Observer must then pull the information from the Subject/Observable object to determine *what* change has happened so it can know how to react.

In the push scenario, the call to the Observer *does* contain information about what has changed (possibly with more details than some Observers need). The information is pushed to the Observers, whether they want it or not.

Both scenarios have their places and you can also have an in-between case where some information is pushed and Observers can pull more if they need it. Which scenario to use depends on the typical information need of the Observers to respond to changes in the Subjects/Observables.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the difference is in who makes the first move. The push model is what most people think of when talking about observers. The source of the event is the most natural choice to control the event's propagation. This is used for things like GUI events. When you click on a button, an event gets pushed into an event loop then a callback gets called.

The pull model is less common, but very useful under certain circumstances, such as for scalability or for getting around firewall or NAT restrictions. Perhaps the most well-known example is [long polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling). The browser initiates the request, then the server holds the connection open, waiting to send the response until an event is generated. [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#design_pull) is another relatively well-known pull-based design, in this case because it allows scalability optimizations such as aggressive batching.

Note that Java's Observable API, which isn't properly called Java's observable pattern, but Java's *implementation* of the pattern, does not directly support a pull model. You can subclass it to pull data from a Kafka broker, then push events from there to the observers, but you can't make it pull all the way. Other implementations, such as [Monix's Iterant for Scala](https://monix.io/api/3.1/monix/tail/Iterant.html), for example, support a pull model all the way through.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! Regarding "_Basically the difference is in who makes the first move_", my understanding is that the first move is made each time by the Subject/Observable and never by the Observer. If you were referring to the general use of these terms, I agree, but my misunderstandings were regarding the Observable Pattern, more precisely, the one that is offered by the Java API. Which one are you referring to ?

Comment: I was talking about the overall pattern because you were calling it a pattern. See my edit about Java's API in particular.